# How to invoke WebApi Controller through URL in ASP.Net MVC Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

How to invoke the WepApi Controller Action in browser URL, Below is the Action Method in APIController.

```
public virtual HttpResponseMessage Export(string ABC, string product, string Release, bool includeInheritedData = false)
{

}
```

Comment: what is the route map for the Api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already its predefined in  Appstart/WebApiConfig.cs for WebApi controllers they were using like below.

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithId", "Api/{controller}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }, new { id = @"\d+" });
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithAction", "Api/{controller}/{action}");
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiGet", "Api/{controller}", new { action = "Get" }, new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get) });
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiPost", "Api/{controller}", new { action = "Post" }, new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Post) });
```

Answer (score 1):

you can define route path and name for web api methods. Using that route can access a API controller action if it is simple Get call and has Anonymous access.

For example:

Suppose this a method in your API controller:

```
[HttpGet,AllowAnonymous][Route("api/register")]
public void Register()
  {

  }
```

You can access it in the URL like: localhost/api/register from browser.This is a simple example to explain thing in simple terms. There are lot of other things involved accessing API methods depending upon various factors like security, requirements etc.

Comment: It Worked by accessing , localhost/Api/controllername/ManExport.

Anyway thanks for your reply.